# How many questions can be asked per day by one user?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, rate-limiting

How many questions can a user ask per day in a math.stackexchange?

Does the number depend on anything?

I tried to find the answer but unsuccessfully.

Comment: See [Über Meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide). Six questions per day, 50 questions per 30-day period.

Comment: more is in any way possible ? and what are demands for that ? thanks

Comment: These are hard limits, system-imposed, you can't get beyond them.

Comment: and hot to handle it here if one has app. 80 questions per month ? 1 month means 30 days from the 1st questions or 1 day of the month to the last day of the month ?

Comment: If you have 80 questions to ask in one month, it means that you're not learning right.

Comment: 1 month means the last 30 days: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2464/question-limit-per-month You can also have a look to other discussions here on meta tagged ([meta-tag:rate-limiting]).

Comment: @Martin I am not too firm in my opinion. But I was operating under the impression that if this question is closed and positively voted, it will stay and so future users with the same question will find it and will read the other post. But you make a good point too about there being possibly too much information in the other post.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'd like some clarification on your statement. What is meant by: "If you have 80 questions to ask in one month, it means that you're not learning right."?

Comment: @iaenstrom: If every single day you have 2.5 new questions, in 99% of the cases, it means that you're just repeating questions. That you're asking what is essentially the same question, again and again and again. If you're not, and you're just doing follow ups, of some sort, that means that you're asking so much, you haven't put the energy to try and solve them yourself. Finally, if you came up with 80 *good* questions that are all independent, then you're not *really* learning per se, you're just asking good questions.

Answer (score 7):

One user can only ask **6 questions per day**. But there is also another limit of **50 questions per month** (more precisely, per 30 days). So if you ask 6 questions every day for several days in a row, it might happen that for some period you will not be able to post questions at all.

These question quotas are not active on all sites in the SE-network. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4742/should-we-ask-for-question-quotas-like-those-that-have-been-available-for-the-bi/4770#4770) you can see when they were introduced on math.SE.

There are also some additional limits for new users and users who asked several questions which were not well-received. (Asking too many questions which  receive many downvotes might even result in [post-ban](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/post-ban/info), which means that you are no longer able to ask questions here.)

You can find much more details in [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide).