# Why have I been blocked from posting questions?

Tags: support, rate-limiting, post-ban

I was about to post another question, but for some reason, I am not allowed to. I haven't received any down votes in the last few months, my last post hasn't had negative feedback, why am I not allowed to post questions? Yesterday I posted a question, but today I can't, why is this so?

Comment: Is it possible that you have reached the [6 questions per day limit](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4742/should-we-ask-for-question-quotas-like-those-that-have-been-available-for-the-bi/4770#4770)?

Comment: No I only posted one question yesterday and none today

Comment: I can't understand why this has happened to me. Today I was about to upload my solution to a question from JBMO, as they had asked me to in my previous post, but I found out that I couldn't upload.

Comment: Did you have the same title to an already posted question?

Comment: No, as soon as I press onto ask question it says

You have reached your question limit
Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.

Comment: I really like maths and want to be part of this community, and I don't know why I've been thrown off

Comment: The details regarding this are often opaque; likely your account is more rate limited than normal due to past activity.

Comment: but I haven't recieved any downvotes, nor negative feedback on my last post

Comment: so even if my account is more rate limited than normal, I haven't recieved any warning showing me that someone disapproves of what I have posted recently

Comment: I have understood that I need to be clearer in my questions, write with the use of Latex and not duplicate any questions accidentally, hence now I look very carefully to make sure that I am not accidentally duplicating a question, that my question is unique, clear, and I try to make it as helpful as possible, for other members of this community

Comment: And the reason I was going to upload today, is because another member of the community, asked me to upload more questions (he asked for this in my previous post).

Comment: "but I haven't recieved any downvotes, nor negative feedback on my last post" so what? I told you that I suspect that you are more rate limited than a normal account, that is you can only post more rarely than other accounts.

Comment: oh now I understand, sorry I hadn't understood the first time, so basically what you are saying is that I will only be able to post every second day or so?

Comment: @MichalisChristofi the delay is unfortunately much longer, I''ll post and answer.

Comment: It might be unrelated, but I will point out that there were some problem s with Stack Exchange network today: [Stack Exchange is intermittently failing at random areas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/352815). One of the symptoms mentioned there is: "Posting was broken..." But it seems unlikely that this would read to the message: "We are no longer accepting ..."

Comment: That actually does kind of make sense, because now that I remember, yesterday, as well as this morning, I checked and it wasn't giving me this particular response, its only around lunchtime today that this started happening

Answer (score 7):

The details of the situation are explained in this  post:

[What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

I will quote some parts (note the passage at the end)

> Automatic bans never expire or "time out." This means that you cannot simply wait for a certain amount of time. If you do not take action, you will never be allowed to freely post again. The only way for the ban to be lifted is by contributing positively to the site in other ways.
> Moderators cannot lift the ban.
> Before you do anything else, fix your existing posts![...]
> Note the emphasis on fixing. Do not delete your posts.

> If you're blocked from asking and unable to improve your existing questions, you'll get the chance to post one new question 6 months after your last question. Your block will still remain once that question is posted, but a single positively-received question could be enough to lift you out of the block.

You seem to be in that situation; you posted after six month and while the post was well received you are still banned. The only options are to do what is recommended above or to wait for another six months to post one more question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response,  but most of my questions which weren't well recieved, was because they were accidentally duplicates, what can I do in this circumstance?

Comment: That does not seem to be an accurate paraphrase of the situation.

Comment: I have one question with -3 votes and another two which are duplicates, despite having positive votes, could you please explain to me what I can do?

Comment: @MichalisChristofi two thirds of your questions are deleted, often closed (not as dupe) and with negative score.

Comment: True you are right there, but my big question is, what can I do now, instead of waiting 6 months? Among my questions which are not deleted, as I stated earlier, the majority of the ones with negative feedback are duplicates. So no edit can make those any more valid. So what is it that I can do apart from waiting another 6 months?

Comment: @MichalisChristofi improve the deleted ones to get them undeleted etc.

Comment: Yes but as I have less than 10k reputation, I can't see my deleted posts

Comment: as they were deleted over 2 months ago

Comment: @MichalisChristofi if you have a link I think you still can see them. If you don't I think you can find them on SEDE. Frankly, you did nothing about this for ages; I'm not very motivated to go out of my way to talk you through that all.  The information is there; now help yourself.

Comment: ok thanks a lot

Comment: my best wishes, sta safe and have a great weekend

Comment: @MichalisChristofi once your soft ban is lifted, you can delete and recreate your account to possible lift the system ban because it will not associate you anymore with the previous posts( don't do it while you're banned)